# is there any way to generate value for nested variable while generating an project from maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

Is there any way to generate value for nested variable while generating an project from maven archetype?

I have an statement like this in current archetype  which I will replace when I generate an project out of it.

I will be making specailzed-folder a required property in **archetype-metadata.xml**

```
${specialized-folder}.tomcat.jdbc.user=xyz

tomcat-jdbc-user=${specialized-folder}.tomcat.jdbc.user
```

now let us say I need to get xyz into another file, I am doing this

```
<property name="username" value="${${tomcat-jdbc-user}" />
```

If specialize-folder is passed as company then

```
company.tomcat.jdbc.user=xyz
```

how can I get xyz in property name username?

Please let me know if there is other way around. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see instead of using ${${tomcat-jdbc-user}, we can use ${${specialized-folder}.tomcat.jdbc.user} and verified it's working fine.

Thanks.